# cannot download file from sftp in apache camel and no failure logs printed

Tags: maven, apache-camel, sftp, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I am truing to connect to ftp server using sftp but cannot seem to connect.
There is no error in connectivity or credentials

Camel Context.xml

```
    <route>
<from id="_from1" uri="sftp://user@localhost:22/data/test/user?noop=true&amp;password=XXXXXX"/>
     <log id="_log1" message="downloading ${file:name}"/>
     <to id="_to1" uri="file:ftpclient"/>
</route>
```

i have added the dependency:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-ftp</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

The logs are as follows:

```
[                      Thread-4] RawBuilder                     INFO  Copy thread finished.
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator starting
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator started
[         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintContainerImpl         INFO  Bundle sftp_connect/1.0.0.SNAPSHOT is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint]
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Attempting to start CamelContext: _context1
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Apache Camel 2.21.0.fuse-710018-redhat-00001 (CamelContext: _context1) is starting
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  StreamCaching is enabled on CamelContext: _context1
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] ManagedManagementStrategy      INFO  JMX is enabled
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] DefaultManagementAgent         INFO  ManagementAgent detected JVM system properties: {org.apache.camel.jmx.createRmiConnector=true}
[KTOP-980NI68:1099/jmxrmi/camel] DefaultManagementAgent         INFO  JMX Connector thread started and listening at: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://DESKTOP-980NI68:1099/jmxrmi/camel
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] DefaultStreamCachingStrategy   INFO  StreamCaching in use with spool directory: C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\camel\camel-tmp-81aa83b2-0e29-4496-a4b9-17a9ff951952 and rules: [Spool > 128K body size]
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] SftpEndpoint                   INFO  Endpoint is configured with noop=true so forcing endpoint to be idempotent as well
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] SftpEndpoint                   INFO  Using default memory based idempotent repository with cache max size: 1000
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] SftpOperations                 INFO  Known host file not configured, using user known host file: C:\Users\Lenovo/.ssh/known_hosts
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Route: _route1 started and consuming from: sftp://user@localhost:/data/test/user?&noop=true&password=xxxxxx
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] BlueprintCamelContext          INFO  Apache Camel 2.21.0.fuse-710018-redhat-00001 (CamelContext: _context1) started in 1.320 seconds
```

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

when I make the JSCH log levels to info it gives:

```
[ Blueprint Event Dispatcher: 1] SftpOperations                 INFO  JSCH -> Connection established
```

Comment: So is there any files in /data/test/user ? They are not consuming, right ?

Comment: There are files present in the path, its just not consuming

Comment: Log showing thats all right and that is strange. Is there any chance that route already consumed files ? Because you using noop=true that causing using in-memory idempotent repository preventing consuming already consumed files.

Comment: I have entered log in my route, if consumed it should show in logs right?

Comment: As @c0ld said, as you have noop set, it behaves as if there are no file if they have all already been consumed, so you wouldn't get any log to say this file has already been consumed. If you want to re-consume files that have already been consumed (for re-testing for example) you will have to stop the route and restart it.

Comment: @Screwtape but log showing like bundle was restarted and after that there is no consuming. I'm stuck =)

Comment: i restarted the route multiple times facing the same issue @Screwtape

Comment: I assume you have a number of files in a directory called user/test/data below the user which are accessible to the user "user". Are you running on Linux and if so is SELinux enabled?

Comment: Add 2 more possibility. 1. Path in Unix/Linux is case sensitive. 2. Camel is using relative path and some type of server is NOT start at "/" when login

Comment: Did you create a sftp user and provided the home directory correctly? The path in the uri is technically a relative path of the home directory of the sftp user.

Comment: Yes i have done exactly as mentioned above. I am not using UNIX system, and the directory path is case sensitive as in the server. I'm not using absolute path, I tried once but the eclipse compiler converts it automatically giving a warning. Yes, i have successfully created a sftp user provided path correctly. Camel does not take absolute path after camel 2.16 and im using 2.21

Answer (score 0):

SFTP camel takes path relative to home/user folder instead of absolute path. Search if this path "data/test/user" is present somewhere in home/user folder, that will be the location it is picking files from. You can always enable debug logging while running the code for better understanding of what is happening. https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-do-i-enable-debug-logging.html

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you. Also, sum up your answer in case the link stops working in the future.